# FormControl number values are set but don't display until touched

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to populate the form input fields with data from the model that is to be edited. The text input fields work fine but the number fields stay empty until I click on them, some until I click on them and all previous number fields... What could be causing this issue?
Here is the html:

```
<form [formGroup]="servis.editCarFrom" style="width: 320px;">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form">
            <div>
                <label for="marka">Marka:</label>
                <input  id="marka" formControlName="marka" class="form-control"  value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('marka').value}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <div>
                <label for="model">Model:</label>
                <input  id="model" formControlName="model" class="form-control" value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('model').value}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <div>
                <label for="brojMesta">Broj mesta:</label>
                <input type="number" id="brojMesta" formControlName="brojMesta" class="form-control" value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('brojMesta').value}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <div>
                <label for="godiste">Godiste:</label>
                <input type="number" id="godiste" formControlName="godiste" class="form-control" value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('godiste').value}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <div>
                <label for="cena">Cena:</label>
                <input type="number" id="cena" formControlName="cena" class="form-control" value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('cena').value}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <div>
                <label for="brzaRezervacija">Brza rezervacija:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="brzaRezervacija" formControlName="brzaRezervacija" class="form-control" value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('brzaRezervacija').value}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="tip">Tip vozila:</label>
            <select id="tip" formControlName="tip" class="form-control">
                <option selected value>{{servis.editCarForm.get('tipVozila').value}}</option>
                <option *ngFor="let t of GetTipovi()">
                    {{t}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <button (click)="Save()">Sacuvaj</button>
        <button style="float: right;" (click)="Nazad()">Nazad</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is where I set the control values:

```
InitEditCarForm(kola: any) {
    let naziv = kola.naziv.split('-');
    let marka = naziv[0];
    let model = naziv[1];
    let tip = TipVozila[kola.tipVozila];
    this.editCarForm.controls.marka.setValue(marka);
    this.editCarForm.controls.model.setValue(model);
    this.editCarForm.controls.godiste.setValue(kola.godiste);
    this.editCarForm.controls.cena.setValue(kola.cena);
    this.editCarForm.controls.brojMesta.setValue(kola.brojMesta);
    this.editCarForm.controls.brzaRezervacija.setValue(kola.brzaRezervacija);
    this.editCarForm.controls.tipVozila.setValue(kola.tipVozila);

    this.editCarForm.markAllAsTouched();
  }
```

This method is very slow, I have to wait a few seconds after the page has loaded before the values get updated, and not all of them get updated. Is there a better way to do this? If not how can I properly update the number fields so they display their intended value on their own once the page has loaded?

Comment: As said @nclskfm you can do a "setValue" directly on your formGroup, see it as your main model.
Then as you are binding the values with formGroup and formControl to your inputs, you can remove all the "value" attribute on your template , like "value="{{servis.editCarForm.get('cena').value}}""

Answer (score 1):

you can initiate values while you declare your form group

```js
formGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstInput: new FormControl(value1),
   secondInput: new FormControl(value2)
});
```

And if you want to update values for your form group, you can use `setValue` or `patchValue` on your form group directly. `setValue` requires, that you update all inputs. So if you have a from group with three form controls, and you want to update only two controls, you have to use `patchValue. For example:

```js
formGroup = new FormGroup({
control1: new FormControl('init value'),
control2: new FormControl(null),
control3: new FormControl(12) 
});

function updateAllValues() {
  this.formGroup.setValue({
    control1: 'new value',
    control2: true,
    control3: 42
  );
}

function updateSomeValues() {
  this.formGroup.setValue({
    control1: 'new extra value',
    control3: 42
  );
}
```

Comment: The values are initiated properly, that's not the issue. The values don't show up until i click on the input field.

Comment: The issue is that you’re using values on formcontrols.. the formControl already takes care of setting the value (2 way) so remove all this value attributes first as this is probably part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This similiar problem was solved for me by simply having an *ngIf on the  with all the containing lists/methods that might not have been initialized at start.

For example, your method "GetTipovi()" is probably returning a list that is not finished when the  started to load, however due to two-way binding, your  loop still gets the values whenever "GetTipovi()" has something to return.

Adding *ngIf to the  with the list that is returned from "GetTipovi()" will probably solve your problem.